# Xcode remove duplicate Pod Frameworks

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I have duplicate frameworks for versions 11.0 and 11.3. How do I remove these frameworks when they reside in the Pod workspace? When I right click them, the delete function is grayed out.

Notice ducplicate GoogleUtilities, Marshal, and nanopb.frameworks.

[image]